I need to add a second category filter
I need help with adding a second category filter to a site.  I have the first one working but not sure how to add a second one.  The first one will choose the type of podcasts and the second needs to choose by a name.  I already have the post types and categories setup in the functions.php file for the podcasts categories so would I need to add anything additional there since it will be using the same categories just filtering them in a different way?
And would I need to set them up as a parent category with child categories for each filter?  For example one parent name with the Type of Podcasts to filter and one with the Names to filter?
Also how do I specify each filter to show just one with types in the dropdown and one with just names in the second dropdown?
    <?php
$filter = get_query_var( 'podcast_category_filter' );

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'          => 'podcast_category',
    'selected'          => sanitize_text_field( $filter ),
    'name'              => 'podcast_category_filter',
    'hide_empty'        => false,  
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
    'value_field'       => 'slug',
    'echo'              => false,  
    'show_option_all'   => 'All podcasts',
    'option_none_value' => 0       
);
$select_category_html = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
?>

<form method='GET'>
    <?php echo $select_category_html ?>
    <button type='submit'>Filter</button>
</form>

<div class="podcasts">

<ul>
    <?php $tax_query = array();

    
    if ( ( 0 != $filter ) && is_string( $filter ) && ( '' != $filter ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'podcast_category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => sanitize_text_field( $filter ),
            )
        );
    }

    // Create a secondary query to avoid using the main query.
    $args = array_merge(
        array( 'post_type' => 'podcast' ),
        array( 'tax_query' => $tax_query )
    );
    $podcast_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $podcast_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $podcast_query->have_posts() ) : $podcast_query->the_post(); ?>

<li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

So both the podcast types and the podcast names, are podcast_category items? Then you will have to work with parent and child categories, yes, because otherwise how would you differentiate between them in the first place?

Thank you!  So how would I adjust the above code to include another dropdown of categories and set the two apart with the parent categories?

I still can't tell what your actual scenario here is, so please give a proper explanation. Did you stick type and name into one single category? If so, a)why?, and b) what does that actually look like? Is the selection of a specific type then somehow supposed to only show names that belong to that type, or still all names?

Thank you for your help, I ended up figuring it out.

I figured it out.  I added parent and child categories and then added another Query but included parent => cat_ID to each array and added the parent ID's and it worked.
